# Javascript class as object's child

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a graphics library in JavaScript. I want to make a `Rectangle` class, but I don't want to have it in the global scope, as all of my functions etc. are in an object called `L2D`.

This is my code:

```
// "primitive" objects
L2D.Vec2 = (x, y) => {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

// interfaces
L2D.Drawable = () => {
    this.fillColor = '#FFF';
    this.outlineColor = '#000';
}

L2D.Transformable = () => {
    this.position = L2D.Vec2(0, 0);
}

L2D.Shape = () => {
    L2D.Drawable(); L2D.Transformable();

    this.vertices = [];

    this.draw = (context) => {
        context.beginPath();
        for (let i in this.vertices) {
            let v = this.vertices[vert]
            if (i == 0) context.moveTo(v.x, v.y);
            else context.lineTo(v.x, v.y);
        }
        context.closePath();

        if (this.fillColor) {
            context.fillStyle = this.fillColor;
            context.fill();
        }
        if (this.outlineColor) {
            context.strokeStyle = this.outlineColor;
            context.fill();
        }
    }
}

// classes
L2D.Rectangle = (x, y, w, h) => {
    L2D.Shape();

    this.vertices = [
        L2D.Vec2(x, y),
        L2D.Vec2(x + w, y),
        L2D.Vec2(x + w, y + h),
        L2D.Vec2(x, y + h)
    ]
}
```

The problem is, I cannot call `new L2D.Rectangle(x, y, w, h)`. I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: L2D.Rectangle is not a constructor
```

I have tried doing `function L2D.Rectangle` and `class L2D.Rectangle`, but both result in an error (complaining about that dot).

How can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrow functions cannot rebind the this context. The this is already bound to the lexical scope. For new to work, you should have plain functions.

```
L2D.Rectangle = function(x, y, w, h) {};
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought arrow functions are functionally equivalent to regular anonymous functions, but apparently there are differences.